# Rails and MySQL - structure Product with sizes and prices

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What is the proper way to structure models and migrations in Rails so I can have relationships like this:

[image: Relationships]

I think the image is clear enough but:

1. One product can have different sizes
2. A size can have different prices dependent on the product it is associated with.

I am in a school project and the only guy who has ever done something with code, and we need to structure something similar to this (it's biological but the idea is the same).

Would generating:

**For product:**

```
rails generate model Product name:string

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sizes
    has_many :prices
end
```

**For size:**

```
rails generate model Size size:string product:references

class Size < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
    has_many :prices
end
```

**For price:**

```
rails generate model Price price:decimal size:references product:references

class Price < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sizes
    has_many :products
end
```

solve my problem?

I am in the middle of reading [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) but it is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be like this-

`Product` model:

```
has_many :sizes
has_many :prices, through: :sizes
```

`Size` model:

```
 has_many :prices
 belongs_to :product
```

`Price` model:

```
belongs_to :size
```

Comment: I think this would be efficient, wouldn't it? This is a small project for now, but it can probably have up to 100.000 records, so I am looking a way to structure it properly. Would you mind sharing how would a migration file look like? Would price have "t.belongs_to :product, index: true" and "t.belongs_to :size, index: true"?

Comment: **1** `rails g model production`
**2** `rails g model size product:references`
**3** `rails g model price size:references`

It would be enough to just have `size_id` column in `prices`  table.